# Only apply style to non-nested controls in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

In WPF, I'm not happy with the default styling of some controls, like `<Button />` which by default doesn't have the same dimensions as a native Win32 button. Fortunately it's easy to fix by applying a MinWidth and Margin property.

Rather than manually applying those properties to every `<Button />` in XAML I have them set in a style in my `App.xaml` file's `ResourceDictionary`, like so:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="73" />
</Style>
```

However, this means that *all* buttons in the UI now have this style, such as buttons nested within `<DatePicker />` and even `<MenuItem />`, making the UI even worse.

I know I can add `x:Key="b"` to the `<Style />` and then change my XAML to `<Button Style={StaticResource b} />` but this seems just as cumbersome as manually setting properties on every control instance.

Is there a way to apply a style only to *my* controls and not controls nested in other UI components? i.e. I want all of my `<Button />` instances in my own XAML have the same style, but not buttons in built-in WPF controls or any third-party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own type of button and apply the style on it:

```
public class MyButton: Button {}

...

<Style TargetType="yourNamespace:MyButton">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="73" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Thing is, I'm finding myself needing to set styles (margins, padding, dimensions, etc) on almost every built-in WPF control. I would have to subclass almost every WPF control then. It just doesn't "seem right">

Comment: Also, is there any way to have a style that only applies to elements that are children of another control? (e.g. "style only `<Button>` instances that are immediate children of `<Border />`)?

Comment: @Dai - If you include the Style in the resources for the Border then it will apply only to the children.

Comment: @user3690202 Suppose you have Borders that are children of the Border. Won't the style that targets Border affect the parent as well as the children?

Comment: @KyleDelaney probably, but that's kind of what he wanted or implied that he wanted. TBH, this comment is a few years old and I don't do much WPF anymore - I feel like it's a dying technology that even MS have turned their back on. It's incredibly powerful and flexible, but it is almost unlearnably complicated especially in cases like this. These days I fall back more onto WinForms controls just because they are far easier to write with performance in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can derive from `Button` and make your own type, using the custom `Margin` and `MinWidth` values.

There's no need to create a separate style for this, or to even create a new .xaml control, just an inherited class will do.

```
public class MyButton: Button 
{
    public MyButton()
    {
        Margin = new Thickness(4);
        MinWidth = 73;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to target specific buttons then there's no way around using x:Key. There is nothing wrong with explicitly styling your buttons, but there are tricks that allow you to group style things selectively using x:Key.

First, create your style with a key in app.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="73"/>
</Style>
```

Apply a style `BasedOn` your key to a parent container of your buttons

```
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <!--Apply your button style to contents of StackPanel-->
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}">
                <!--You can add extra setters to the style without affecting the original-->
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="This is my button"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <Button Content="Test1"/>
        <Button Content="Test2"/>
        <Button Content="Test3"/>
        <Button Content="Test4"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--Buttons built into DatePicker are unaffected-->
    <DatePicker/>
</DockPanel>
```

Also FYI your style doesn't necessarily need to exist in app.xaml.

```
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <!--Apply your button style to contents of StackPanel-->
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="73"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <Button Content="Test1"/>
        <Button Content="Test2"/>
        <Button Content="Test3"/>
        <Button Content="Test4"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--Buttons built into DatePicker are unaffected-->
    <DatePicker/>
</DockPanel>
```